# javascript resource does not run in WebBrowser control (WinForm)

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm building a C# app (WinForm).  I have a javascript component that changes the background color of the webpage.  If I put the JS directly into the HTML file it works (ie the background color of the webBrowser appears red).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Title</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="FFFFFF">
<HR>
<script>
    var setBackColor = function () {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    setBackColor();
</script>
<H1>This is a Header</H1>
<H2>This is a Medium Header</H2>
<P> This is a new paragraph!
<P>
    <B>This is a new paragraph!</B>
    <BR><B><I>This is a new sentence without a paragraph break, in bold   italics.</I></B><BR>
<HR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

When I put the JS in an external file and try to access it through the path shown, I get an error that reads...

"The value of the property 'setBackColor' is null or undefined, not a Function object."

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Title</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="FFFFFF">
<HR>
<script type="text/javascript" src=c:\users\local user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\HTMLTestApp\HTMLTestApp\Scripts\JavaScript1.js></script>
<body onload="setBackColor()"></body>
<H1>This is a Header</H1>
<H2>This is a Medium Header</H2>
<P> This is a new paragraph!
<P>
    <B>This is a new paragraph!</B>
    <BR><B><I>This is a new sentence without a paragraph break, in bold italics.</I></B><BR>
<HR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am a complete novice coder, so I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is more of an HTML and javascript thing than it is a web browser control thing.

Take a look at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp) on the src attribute of scripts.

So first off, you will need the URL for your src attribute in quotes.
Secondly people usually have some kind of directory structure setup with the webpages so they normally use relative paths so that when they copy over from Dev environment on to their webserver it still works.

So if your script folder is one below the folder with the HTML in it then you would use this as your script tag :

```
<script src="Scripts/JavaScript1.js"> </script>
```

Also you have your body tag declared **twice**. That is too many times.